# Result is not print when value is 0

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, eloquent

This is a function, its show result but when result 0 or null value, its not print and put blank space.when result is 0 its not print, what to do?

```
$holding_time = DB::table('trade')
        ->select(DB::raw('trade.*'))
        ->join('exchanges', 'trade.exchange_id', '=', 'exchanges.id')
        ->where('trade.user_id', $user_id)
        ->select(DB::raw('SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,buy_datetime, sell_datetime)) as first_hour_total_time'))
        ->first();

    DD("$holding_time");
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement to return another value when `$holding_time` is null

Comment: what do you want to print when result is null or zero?

Comment: when Result is zero then print 0 -@RamAnji

Comment: Have you tried `response()->json($holding_time ?? 'NULL');`? (PHP 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check null value before return that

```
if($holding_time)
    return response()->json(['time' => $holding_time], 200);
else
    return response()->json(['time' => 'null'], 200);
```

Also you can use `firstOrFail()` to check output of query fo any problem ( if you want have a result always )

You can log output to see query result

```
Log::info($holding_time);
```

Comment: No, its not useful for me, any other idea?? -@Arash Hatami

Comment: Try to log that. Do you have 0 in result ? @KinnariPrajapati look at updated answer

Comment: Actually, I want very short code. Therefore, I am finding new idea for this.

Comment: Yes I have a result in 0 but did'nt print, canyou guide me use only one line(short code) in function and print result 0?

Comment: `response()->json($holding_time ?? 0);` @KinnariPrajapati